# DNS takes forever - Using Pingdom

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare, monitoring

So I am using the new CloudFlare.. I have a GoDaddy shared hosting account, which i know isn't the fastest in the world, but DNS seems very slow. I have a Wordpress blog configured as the following:

example.com/subdir (Location of Wordpress)
example.com (Actual Site)

This change was made using Wordpress Codex.

When I use pingdom, or just do it myself, There is a very long interchange from when i type in www.example.com to change to example.com or vice versa.

DNS on Cloudflare is setup as the following:

A example.com points to IP Address
A www points to IP Address
CNAME www points to example.com

Is there something wrong here? Pingdom says theres a huge wait time, and I notice it just typing in the site itself. Waits forever (before even loading a single thing.) Once the wait is over, then everything loads lighting fast.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is that takes forever here. One question: Why on earth do have 2 DNS records for `www` (both `CNAME` and `A`)?

Comment: Just to see if that would help. It takes forever if I type in domain.com to transfer into www.domain.com

Comment: transfer into www.domain.com? So you have a redirect set up on the server, and that takes a long time?

Comment: Does pingdom specifically say that the delay is in name resolution?  And your `CNAME` record plus `A` record on the same name is invalid.. they shouldn't be letting you configure it that way.

Comment: You should get rid of the A record for `www` for starters.

Comment: If only there were some domain name explicitly reserved for examples... [oh, wait](http://www.iana.org/domains/example/).

Comment: Without your [telling everyone what is reported to you by your testing tool](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html), in detail without [lying about domain names](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-obscure-your-dns-data.html) or other such tomfoolery, no-one is going to be able to diagnose this problem for you. The world is not clairvoyant. [You haven't yet demonstrated that this is even a DNS problem in the first place](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-narrow-problem-locus.html).

Answer (score 3):

You're NOT supposed to have CNAME together with an A record, if it even works it can cause lookup issues, the record not being available or worse (the zone not loading at all). So remove the CNAME and point it to the IP (saves one lookup too). Or leave the CNAME and keep the A.

Comment: The best thing to do is to CNAME `www` to domain.com.

Comment: +1 -- This zone configuration is illegal (CNAMEs must be the *only* type of record with a given name) - I'm surprised their software let you create such a thing.  (See [RFC 1912](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt), section 2.4)

Comment: @MDMarra not necessarily. To easily maintain large zones, CNAMEs are preferable, but from a performance point of view, an A record is actually a little faster to resolve, since the DNS server doesn't have to verify an additional A record when answering queries matching a CNAME record.

Comment: This answer addresses an immediately obvious misconfiguration, but doesn't actually answer the question as posed.  This particular misconfiguration does not in general cause long delays in WWW page loading, which is what the questioner has asked about.

Comment: @JdeBP It COULD be the explanation for the delays too. If the zone doesn't load properly on one of the nameservers because of the misconfiguration, lookups might have to wait to attempt the other nameserver until they can lookup the IP and retry. People underestimate the influence DNS can have on situations like this.

Comment: In practice, the world is quite the reverse of your contention.  People _overestimate_ the rôle of the DNS, and blame the DNS for things which are nothing to do with it.  "My WWW page is slow to load.  How do I fix my DNS?" isn't exactly an unusual question.  And "It could be the DNS if these bizarre circumstances, which _aren't the way that CloudFlare even works in the first place_, obtain." is, I regret to inform you, yet more reaching for the DNS as the problem locus without even looking for the problem locus.

Comment: @JdeBP given the low level of detail in the question and the obvious DNS misconfiguration, there's not a whole lot else for us to go on. I don't see you proposing an alternative solution.

Comment: @JdeBP Cloudflare needs to look up DNS to reach the main site in the first place, I assume. So does pingdom. If DNS is improperly configured so the zonefile doesn't load (for example) on the master NS, requests there will not respond properly and might have to try again (after certain values of timeout) and try again with the second NS in the next attempt. This IS very often the explanation for odd delays when something "takes time and then suddenly starts to work lightning fast". I see it almost on a weekly basis on my customers environments (our company manage ~3500 servers).